# What assembly is SerializeableAttribute in?

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm trying to set up serialization for a class. When I added:

```
[Serializeable]
```

I got the error:
"The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I added System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap and System.Runtime.Serialization but they didn't work. I also tried to find the other assemblies listed on the documentation page. I only found mscorlib in the VS Reference Manager and it was already added.

I wrote the code like so:

```
[Serializeable]
public class Test { }
```

Edit: I also tried:

```
[Serializeable()]
public class Test { }
```

I expected the code to compile without errors.

Edit: fixed wrong name for an assembly

Comment: What do you mean you added the assemblies? You didnt provide enought code. Did you also import them with a "using"?

Comment: And btw it's `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap` not `System.Runtime.Formatters.Soap`

Comment: Kindly check a working example easily Googled like this one : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=netframework-4.8#definition before posting

Comment: @AviMeltser I forgot to import them as they were not availible in intellisense, wich usually happens for usings. I just added the following imports anyways: using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap; I still get errors

Comment: @AviMeltser By adding assemblies I mean throught the Visual Studio Reference Manger. The example you linked does not show this step.

Comment: The error is that System.Runtime.Serialization "does not exist"

Comment: Check .net versions of the assemblies you added. Make sure you they are compatible with the version of your assembly.

Comment: Also, use the attribute as such : `[Serializeable()]` instead of `[Serializeable]`

Answer (score 0):

Per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=netframework-4.8), the `SerializableAttribute` type can be found in the following assemblies:

- System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll
- mscorlib.dll
- netstandard.dll
- System.Runtime.dll

---

**EDIT**

It may be easier to try the below.  There may be namespace conflicts.

```
[System.SerializableAttribute]
public class Test {}
```

Comment: How can I add these? I can't find them in the Reference Manager.